# How do you pronounce "mayor"?

Tags: pronunciation

I have been split between two pronunciations of "mayor".

Most of the people I talk to pronounce it "mair" (like the horse).

But if you look on [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mayor) the main pronunciation is "mey-er".

I wanted some clarification on which is the correct way and why there are two different versions of the word.

Comment: This is a British/American split, probably having to do with rhotic/non-rhotic dialects. Most Americans wouldn't dream of pronouncing *mare* and *mayor* the same, and that may be why Dictionary.com gives the pronunciation the way it does.

Comment: @PeterShor: I agree for the most part, except some southern drawls might make "mayor" sound like "mare."  Maybe it's a British/American split, as you suggest, or maybe it's a Mason/Dixon split, too.

Comment: As an SAE speaker, I don't. But because rhoticity and levels and lengths of diphthong- and triphthonging differ a good bit, it's almost certainly the case somewhere down here.

Comment: Not necessary a BrE/AmE split. Mayor Richard J. Daley ["was known by many Chicagoans as "Da Mare"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_J._Daley)  ("The Mayor").

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The British have been pronouncing "mayor" with one syllable since at least 1780 (See Thomas Sheridan's 1780 [*"General Dictionary of the English Language"*](http://books.google.com/books?id=mCY-AAAAcAAJ&pg=PT596&dq=Sheridan+dictionary+mayor&hl=en&sa=X&ei=5ZJeUqeHPILE4APLs4GoDw&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=mayor&f=false) in Google books). The general American pronunciation is two syllables.

Comment: Can confirm that (my part of) Canada also follows the Queen's English here, too.

Answer (score 2):

I'm Australian and use the 'mare' pronunciation. I'm used to hearing Yanks say 'may-or', though - in movies and on TV.  That said, I've just seen NYC's Mayor LaGuardia being sworn in on the History Channel - in the 1930s - both he and the officiating judge clearly said 'MARE'.

Paul

Answer (score -4):

The proper pronunciation would be as given in the Dictionary.com: `mey-er`.

However, when you happen to speak fast as is usual in conversations the stretch in the 'y-er' is reduced, making it sound like 'ma-ir' .

In case you wish to hear it clearly, do have a look at news videos or on TV. I'm sure you can notice how the pronunciation varies with the tempo of speech.

Comment: -1 for the phrase "proper pronunciation", based on one dictionary.  Other on-line dictionaries give both one- and two-syllable pronunciations.  Peter Shor's answer is better